# Java get values from json file using simple json lib

Tags: java, json

I have json file with this format:

```json
{
  "1": {
    "path": ["C"],
    "Des": ["D"]
  },
  "2": {
    "path": ["A"],
    "Des": ["D"]
  },
  "3": {
    "path": ["C"],
    "Des": ["B"]
  }
}
```

I want to get values in class objects
and using this code to see result before added it to arraylist
objects

```java
import java.io.FileReader;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/dell/Desktop/streams.json"));
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONObject json0 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get(0);
            System.out.println(json0);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any ArrayList in your code. What objects do you want to put into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `jsonObject` is not array, try to do this:

```
jsonObject.get("1")
```

Instead of this:

```
jsonObject.get(0)
```

Comment: thanks but this not useful I need to get the ( "1" , "2" , "3") from JSONObject jsonObject which contain 3 Json object

Answer (score 0):

To get all keys of the json object simply do:

```java
jsonObject.keySet()
```

If you want to put keys to the list:

```java
List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>((Set<String>) jsonObject.keySet());
```